# How can I cancel this event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I have four videos in one div and I have another one video in another div I have done an event listener that will apply for the all five video as you see

```js
var videoAct = document.querySelectorAll('video'),
    mainVideo = document.getElementById('mainvideo'), // this id for the video in (mainV )
    allVideo = document.getElementById('allvideo'), // this id for the div that contain the four video
    mainV = document.getElementById('mainv'); // this id for the div that contain one video

videoAct.forEach(function(video) {
    video.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        this.play();
        video.muted = true;
    });
    video.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        this.pause();
    });
})
```

so how I remove this event listener from my one video in (mainV ) so that I work with its default setting

Comment: you can use removeEventListener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: Why to remove the listener when you can simply ignore that element while adding event listener. @zb22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `id` value of the video which you want to ignore inside the `for` loop so that the listener is not added to that video.

```
var videoAct = document.querySelectorAll('video'),
   mainVideo = document.getElementById('mainvideo'), // this id for the video in (mainV )
   allVideo = document.getElementById('allvideo'), // this id for the div that contain the four video
   mainV = document.getElementById('mainv'); // this id for the div that contain one video

videoAct.forEach(function(video){
  if(video.id !== 'mainvideo') {
    video.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
       this.play();
       video.muted = true;  
    });
    video.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
       this.pause();    
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks alot man it work just fine :)

Comment: @MohamedNagehOtafy glad to help. :)

Comment: if i want to change the source of the video with ( id = mainVideo ) to any source from the four video when i click on any of them i try to add this code to if statement but it didn't work 

  -->  videoAct.forEach(function(video){
 if(video.id !== 'mainvideo') {
 video.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
 this.play();
 video.muted = true;
 
 });
 video.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
  this.pause();
 });

 video.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var source = this.hasAttribute('src').value;
  mainVideo.src = src[source];
 })
}
})  <--

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to remove your event, just don't apply it...

```
var allVideo = document.getElementById('allvideo'), // this id for the div that contain the four video
   videoAct = allVideo.querySelectorAll('video'); // look for videos only in the #allvideo div

videoAct.forEach(function(video){
   video.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
      this.play();
      video.muted = true;  
   });
   video.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
      this.pause();    
   });
})
```

Comment: i try but it didn't work , it give me this error in console ( allVideo.forEach is not a function )

Comment: there is no `allVideo.forEach()` in the code I gave, so there is something wrong in your code, not in my answer... you should do `forEach()` on `videoAct` not on `allVideo` as `videoAct` contains list of `video` elements and `allVideo` is only a `div` that contains those `video` elements